# How to return list of class objects sorted based on attribute value

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm creating a class called `Game`. The objects of the class have the following attributes:

- name
- genre
- release_date

This is the class:

```
class Game:


    num_of_objects = 0

    def __init__(self, name, genre, year=1990, month=1, day=1):
        """
        Class Constructure: Returns a Game object whose parameters are:
        name: String
        genre: String
        data: YYYY-MM-DD
        """   
        self.name = name
        self.genre = genre
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.release_date = self.year + '-' + self.month + '-' + self.day
        Game.num_of_objects += 1 

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def games_by_year():
          print [Game.genre for Game in x]

    def games_by_genre():
        pass

    def games_starting_with():
        pass
```

I would like to create a class method, that returns a list of the Games by genre, and another method that returns a list of games by year. The games in this scenario are just class objects:

```
Halo = Game('Halo', 'shooter', '2019', '11', '12')
```

Also, is there a better way to deal with the date? I'd like to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: why do you mention 'sorting' in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually store the games somewhere when you create them. A class-level list would work:

```
class Game:

    num_of_objects = 0
    games = []

    def __init__(self, name, genre, year=1990, month=1, day=1):
        ...
        self.games.append(self)
```

You can probably remove the `num_of_objects` counter, since that is trivially found from `len(self.games)`. (And note, since you're mutating rather than reassigning the `games` object, you can refer to it directly via `self`.)

Now, your actual methods need to be classmethods, which accept `cls` as the first parameter:

```
@classmethod
def games_by_year(cls):
      return sorted(cls.games, key=lambda g: g.year)

@classmethod
def games_by_genre(cls):
      return sorted(cls.games, key=lambda g: g.genre)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Any way to call the method in a such a way it returns the actual list of game genres instead of :                      [<__main__.Game at 0x1eb62f432e8>,
 <__main__.Game at 0x1eb62f43fd0>,
 <__main__.Game at 0x1eb62f43ac8>,
 <__main__.Game at 0x1eb62f435f8>]

Comment: Well, if you just want the genres, there is no reason to sort them by a key at all: just `sorted([g.genre for g in self.games])` would do.